# RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage Not Coming after login

Tags: visualforce, community, oauth2

I am using User-Agent OAuth flow for authenticating a community user so that he can access a native android client built using MobileSDK. Also, I have a custom login page for community which redirects to my Community Homepage which i have configured by creating a custom login and landing controller by following this article, https://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2013/10/create-custom-salesforce-communities-login-landing-page/ which works fine since requirement is to send the community user to a custom homepage when accessing via the Web interface. But in the case of doing OAuth in the native android client instead of getting the access token, it is redirecting me to my homepage. I want to know what additional configurations are need to make this work.

Comment: Did you configure SF to use your custom log-in page through your portal settings or how did you configure it? How do you have Oauth Configured to work and what behavior are you expecting? Did you want Oauth to start from your log-in page and then go back to your Community Homepage? Please edit your post with more specifics.

Comment: Have you configured your app with the right oauth permissions?